# Готовые решения для публикации исходного кода с возможностью копирования и HTML/CSS-рендеринга результата

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Задача: вставить в сайт-документацию виджет, который содержит в себе пример исходного кода (HTML/CSS/JavaScript) и результат рендеринга. При этом:

- Должна быть подсветка синтаксиса исходного кода
- Должна быть возможность удобного копирования кода в буфер обмена
- Должна быть возможность отображения кода в оффлайн-режиме, если мы просто открыли HTML-файл на локальном компьютере без подключения к интернету.
- Основные стили документа не должны влиять на рендеринг примера. В целях сокращения времени, на сайте-документации используется библиотека Bootstrap 4 (включая [reboot](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/reboot/)), а этот фреймворк даёт довольно спецефичные (высокоприоритетные) css-правила, которые трудно переопределить. Не хотелось бы, чтобы они влияли на рендеринг примера ...

Решения, которые пробовал и видел:

- Первые три пункта даёт библиотека `prism.js`. Она прекрасно подсвечивает синтаксис для многих языков и можно настроить кнопку "копировать в буфер обмена". Ну а весь остальной интерфейс (например, табы для переключения между исходным кодом и результатом) можно и самому реализовать. Остаётся вопрос, как же оградить отренденный результат примера от bootstrap-стилей.
- Codepen удовлетворяет только первому и четвёртому пунктам. Codepen содержит внутренний iframe, благодаря которому результат рендеринга не зависит от стилей документа. Однако, кнопка "копировать код" отсутствует.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кроме того, без подключения к интернету никакого codepen-виджета отображаться не будет. Можно посмотреть исходный [код того скрипта](https://static.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js), который Codepen получает удалённо (через `script scr=""`) и вставить его себе в JavaScript-файл, однако помимо этого скрипта ещё ведь нужно и свой код примера получить с внешнего codepen.

Близок к идеалу официальный сайт bootstrap: там как код и результат рендеринга, кнопка "копировать код", и всё это работает в оффлайне. Ну а поскольку сам сайт bootstrap построен с использованием своих же стилей, то влияние bootstrap-стилей на примеры тут даже нужно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну а лучшее, что я видел - это [сайт-документация Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/components/cards). Виджет ниже имеет ссылку на Codepen, тем не менее, просмотр кода и результата рендеринга доступны в оффлайне. Имеется кнопка копирования кода. Но, опять же, внешние стили влияние имеют.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Остаётся вопрос, как же оградить отренденный результат примера от bootstrap-стилей.
© `iframe` ?

Comment: @qwabra, я правильно понял, что для обеспечения оффлайн-просмотра ссылка в iframe должна вести на статический HTML-файл?

Answer (score 1):

> @qwabra, я правильно понял, что для обеспечения оффлайн-просмотра ссылка в iframe должна вести на статический HTML-файл? – Боков Глеб 7 часов назад

## Создание оффлайн веб приложения (offline web apps)

- просто кэширование - не только не гарантирует, что приложение будет работать "в оффлайн", так ещё и браузер может не "открыть" страницу в отсутствии интернета
  [https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Кэширование](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

для стабильной работы приложения, в условиях отсутствия интернета существует специальное АПИ, которое принимается, допиливается, иногда отклоняется. далее по тексту, я привожу ссылки на спецификацию тех или иных функций и одну статью - "Введение в `Service Worker`'ы".

### устаревшие (Deprecated)

- API cache `*.manifest`
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache
- `window.applicationCache`
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/applicationCache

  > Important: Application Cache is deprecated as of Firefox 44, and is no longer available in insecure contexts from Firefox 60 onwards (bug 1354175, currently Nightly/Beta only). Don't use it to offline websites — consider using `service workers instead`.
- https://caniuse.com/#feat=offline-apps

  > Now deprecated method of defining web page files to be cached using a `cache manifest` file, allowing them to work offline on subsequent visits to the page.

### Web API `Cache` and `service-workers`

> Замечание: Начиная с `Chrome 46`, `Cache API` будут хранить запросы только от безопасных источников, то есть, доступных через `HTTPS`.

- https://caniuse.com/#search=worker
- https://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers
  советую заглянуть во вкладку `Resources` (внизу)
- **Введение в `Service Worker`'ы (20.12.2016)**
  https://getinstance.info/articles/javascript/introduction-to-service-workers/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers
- https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API
  для более точной информации, стоит заглянуть на английскую версию странички
- https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Cache

Comment: Благодарю Вас за подробный ответ! Буду изучать...